# php unset not working in foreach for array

Tags: php, foreach, unset

Server nginx+php-fpm
php 7.2

I tried http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/200d19b2663ee01391b9d0a1745ab677b3f219df

```
$accounts = [
    0 => [
        "active" => true    
    ],
    1 => [
        "active" => false    
    ]
];

foreach($accounts as &$value) {

    if($value['active'] === false) {
         var_dump($value);
         unset($value);
    }

}
unset($value);

print_r($accounts);
```

But unset not working. If use $value = null; in cycle then will set fine.

Comment: Thas because you are unsetting `$accounts[1]['active']` and not `$accounts[1]`

Comment: I can't understand. Why unsetting $accounts[1]['active'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
$accounts = [
        0 => [
            "active" => true    
        ],
        1 => [
            "active" => false    
        ]
];

foreach($accounts as $index=>$value) {

    if($value['active'] === false) {
        var_dump($value);
        unset($accounts[$index]);
    }

}
//unset($value);

print_r($accounts);
```

Comment: Fine, but why not working directly modify with &  Can explain?

Comment: Because when you `unset($value);` you are unsetting `$accounts[1]['active']` and not `$accounts[1]`

Comment: because foreach return each part of array

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-difference-between-foreach-and-for-in-992db038e4c2 and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types  refrence link